# Rspec stub before filter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, stubbing

I have such method in my application controller

```
before_filter :client_signed_in?

def client_signed_in?
    if cookies.signed[:client_id]
        @current_client = Client.find_by_id cookies.signed[:client_id]
        @client_signed_in = true unless @current_client.nil?
    end
end
```

i have tried to stub it

```
allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:client_signed_in?).and_return(true)
```

also

```
allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:@client_signed_in).and_return(true)
```

but in both cases it have returned `nil`

how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController)
  .to receive(:client_signed_in?)
  .and_return(true)
```

The thing is that you stub method of Class, instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

try using
`allow(controller).to receive(:client_signed_in?).and_return(true)`

Or

`allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:client_signed_in?).and_return(true)`

Comment: => NameError: undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Home:0x00000010ecef68>

Comment: try using `allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:client_signed_in?).and_return(true)`